# TCP/.NET: Reading length prefixed buffer or fixed buffer size

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming

I'm currently in the progress of writing my own TCP network library in C# and I want to make sure I'm doing things right.

Currently, I have every packet that gets sent through a socket prefixed with the length. The receiving end will read 4 bytes, convert that to an int, and read that many bytes afterward.

I'm not sure if that's the best approach. Would it be better to just read a fixed amount of bytes and process from there?
In the end, I would just extract 4 bytes from the fixed length buffer and read ahead however much I need.

Here is the code that I currently have to demonstrate my thought process.

```cs
internal void BeginReceive()
{
    ReceiveImpl();
}

protected virtual void ReceiveImpl()
{
    // Should we rather receive a bigger buffer (e.g. 8KB) immediately and then grab the length from that?
    // It would require an internal buffer to store whatever we've already read ahead.
    var recvState = new ReceiveState(new byte[4]);
    Socket.BeginReceive(recvState.Buffer, 0, 4, SocketFlags.None, OnReceiveLength, recvState);
}

private void OnReceiveLength(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var recvState = (ar.AsyncState as ReceiveState)!;
    var bytesRead = Socket.EndReceive(ar, out var errorCode);

    if (errorCode != SocketError.Success)
    {
        // we ain't good fam!
        return;
    }

    if (bytesRead > 0) // should we rather check if we read the 4 bytes we wanted?
    {
        var length = LengthFromBuffer(recvState.Buffer);
        recvState.Buffer = new byte[length];
#if DEBUG
        Console.WriteLine($"Receiving a packet with length of {length}.");
#endif
        // what if the packet is absolutely massive? should we limit the buffer size?
        Socket.BeginReceive(recvState.Buffer, 0, length, SocketFlags.None, OnReceive, recvState);
    }
}

private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var recvState = (ar.AsyncState as ReceiveState)!;
    var bytesRead = Socket.EndReceive(ar, out var errorCode);

    if (errorCode != SocketError.Success)
    {
        // we ain't good fam!
        return;
    }

    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        recvState.BytesReceived += bytesRead;
        if (recvState.BytesReceived < recvState.Buffer.Length)
        {
            Socket.BeginReceive(recvState.Buffer, recvState.BytesReceived,
                recvState.Buffer.Length - recvState.BytesReceived, SocketFlags.None, OnReceive, recvState);
            return;
        }

        OnDataReceived(recvState.Buffer); // this will call BeginReceive again.
    }
}
```

Comment: This depends on what you want to achieve - which is unknown. I've you want to simply treat TCP at the unstructured byte stream it is natively then there is no need to add structure using length bytes. If you want to treat it as a sequence of multi-byte messages instead then prefixing each message with a length is a common approach.

Comment: I guess I didn't properly explain it. I'd still keep the length prefix either way. What I'm worried about is how I'm reading the data from the TCP stream.

The question is if I should be doing multiple calls to receive data using the prefixed length like I'm doing right now or reading a fixed length buffer first and then reading the length off of that and the rest of the data as well.

Comment: It is more efficient to read as much as you can at once since this reduces the amount of system calls - which are comparably expensive. Of course in this case you need to have your own buffer management or build your solution on top of existing buffered readers.